# Grunt php and css generation

Tags: css, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm using yeoman, I've installed grunt-php and I can load php file BUT the css file isn't accessed. Seems the scss isn't complied or the path in my index.php doesn't point to the tmp css file.

I've tried different issues (changing paths) but I'm unable to fix it.

Here is my index.php header :

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>wine trip yo</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor/modernizr.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
```

And here is my Gruntfile :

```
// Generated on 2013-10-14 using generator-webapp 0.4.3
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
// show elapsed time at the end
require('time-grunt')(grunt);
// load all grunt tasks
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-php');

grunt.initConfig({
    // configurable paths
    yeoman: {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    },
    watch: {
        compass: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.php',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
    },
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            livereload: 35729,
            // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    'test',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        }
    },
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.php']
            }
        }
    },
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },
    // not used since Uglify task does concat,
    // but still available if needed
    /*concat: {
        dist: {}
    },*/
    requirejs: {
        dist: {
            // Options: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js
            options: {
                // `name` and `out` is set by grunt-usemin
                baseUrl: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                optimize: 'none',
                // TODO: Figure out how to make sourcemaps work with grunt-usemin
                // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/30
                //generateSourceMaps: true,
                // required to support SourceMaps
                // http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#sourcemapcomments
                preserveLicenseComments: false,
                useStrict: true,
                wrap: true
                //uglify2: {} // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2
            }
        }
    },
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.php'
    },
    usemin: {
        options: {
            dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        },
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.php'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
        // This task is pre-configured if you do not wish to use Usemin
        // blocks for your CSS. By default, the Usemin block from your
        // `index.php` will take care of minification, e.g.
        //
        //     <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
        //
        // dist: {
        //     files: {
        //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //             '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //             '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //         ]
        //     }
        // }
    },
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                //collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true*/
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                src: '*.php',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    'bower_components/sass-bootstrap/fonts/*.*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },
    modernizr: {
        devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
        ],
        uglify: true
    },
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'compass',
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'compass',
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin',
            'htmlmin'
        ]
    },
    bower: {
        options: {
            exclude: ['modernizr']
        },
        all: {
            rjsConfig: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js'
        }
    },
    php: {
        watch: {},
        options: {
            keepalive: true,
            open: true,
            base: 'app'
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'mocha'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'requirejs',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'modernizr',
    'copy:dist',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);


//grunt.registerTask('test', ['php', 'mocha']);
grunt.registerTask('phpwatch', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:server',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:livereload',
    'php:watch', 
    'watch'
]);
```

};

I'm lauching server with the following command :

```
grunt phpwatch
```

The output returns that all files are found except :

```
127.0.0.1:37659 [404]: /styles/main.css - No such file or directory
```

Any advises on how to custom my gruntfile to make css file accessible would be very nice. Thanks.

**LAST VERSION (02/12/2013):**

PS : I currently have a bug in the name/out variable generation in requireJS so I harcoded it but the scss file generation works :

```
// Generated on 2013-10-14 using generator-webapp 0.4.3
'use strict';


module.exports = function (grunt) {
// show elapsed time at the end
require('time-grunt')(grunt);
// load all grunt tasks
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-php');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-requirejs');
//grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ftpush');

grunt.initConfig({
    // configurable paths
    yeoman: {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    },
    watch: {
        compass: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.php',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
    },
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            livereload: 35729,
            // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            //hostname: 'localhost'
            hostname: 'wine-trip.net'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    'test',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        }
    },
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            indent: 5
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.php']
            }
        }
    },
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            //cssDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },
    // not used since Uglify task does concat,
    // but still available if needed
    /*concat: {
        dist: {}
    },*/
    requirejs: {
        dist: {
            // Options: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js
            options: {
                // `name` and `out` is set by grunt-usemin
                name:'app',
                out:'dist',
                //
                baseUrl: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                optimize: 'none',
                // TODO: Figure out how to make sourcemaps work with grunt-usemin
                // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/30
                //generateSourceMaps: true,
                // required to support SourceMaps
                // http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#sourcemapcomments
                preserveLicenseComments: false,
                useStrict: false,//true
                wrap: true
                //uglify2: {} // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2
                /*paths: {
                   myComponent: 'perso/wt.js'
                }*/
            }
        }
    },
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.php'
    },
    usemin: {
        options: {
            dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        },
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.php'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
        // This task is pre-configured if you do not wish to use Usemin
        // blocks for your CSS. By default, the Usemin block from your
        // `index.php` will take care of minification, e.g.
        //
        //     <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
        //
        // dist: {
        //     files: {
        //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //             '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //             '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //         ]
        //     }
        // }
    },
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                //collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true*/
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                src: '*.php',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    'bower_components/sass-bootstrap/fonts/*.*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },
    modernizr: {
        devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
        ],
        uglify: true
    },
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'compass',
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'compass',
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin',
            'htmlmin'
        ]
    },
    bower: {
        options: {
            exclude: ['modernizr']
        },
        all: {
            rjsConfig: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js'
        }
    },
    php: {
        watch: {},
        options: {
            //port: 9000,
            //hostname: 'wine-trip.net',
            keepalive: true,
            open: true,
            base: 'app'
        }
    }/*,
    ftpush: {
      build: {
        auth: {
          host: 'ftp.wine-trip.net',
          port: 21,
          authKey: 'key1'
        },
        src: '/var/www/wine-trip.yo',// 'path/to/source/folder',
        dest: '/www-new/',// '/path/to/destination/folder',
        exclusions: ['path/to/source/folder  .DS_Store', 'path/to/source/folder Thumbs.db', 'dist/tmp'],
        keep: ['/important/images/at/server/*.jpg']
      }
    }*/
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'mocha'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'requirejs',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'modernizr',
    'copy:dist',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);


grunt.registerTask('phpwatch', [
    //'connect:dist:keepalive',
    'useminPrepare',
    'requirejs',
    'bower',
    'compass',
    'php:watch', 
    'watch:livereload',
    'watch'//,
    //'connect:dist:keepalive'
]);

//grunt.registerTask('phpwatch', ['php:watch', 'watch']);

/*grunt.registerTask('phpwatch', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});*/
```

};

Comment: OK I resolved it by adding the line : 'compass', into the phpwatch : grunt.registerTask. I was focused on usemin ...

Comment: Hmmm..same problem here, but your solution doesn't work for me. After 'php:watch' is called with the phpwatch task, 'watch' and all other following methods don't get called. Tryed keepalive: false, but this doesn't work either.
Do 'php:watch' and 'watch' even go along together? Would be nice to have all the flexibility from `grunt server` and working at the same time with `grunt phpwatch`... Any ideas?

Comment: @hugsbrugs can you post the updated gruntfile, for reference?

Answer (score 0):

try this gruntfile.js

install dependencies with npm install.

you need to open localhost:9000 yourself, or just install grunt-open task and configure it.

```
// Generated on 2013-10-23 using generator-webapp 0.4.3
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

var gateway = require('gateway');
var phpGateway = function (dir){
    return gateway(require('path').resolve(dir), {
        '.php': 'php-cgi'
    });
};

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // show elapsed time at the end
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        // configurable paths
        yeoman: {
            app: 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },
        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true
            },
            coffee: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:dist']
            },
            coffeeTest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:test']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.php',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // livereload: 35729,
                // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: '0.0.0.0'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    // open: true,
                    // base: [
                    //     '.tmp',
                    //     '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    // ]
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            require('connect-livereload')(),
                            phpGateway('app'),
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'app')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    /*base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        'test',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]*/
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'test'),
                            mountFolder(connect, '<%= yeoman.app %>')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    /*open: true,
                    base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'*/
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, '<%= yeoman.dist %>')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: false,
                    urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.php']
                }
            }
        },
        coffee: {
            options: {
                bare: true
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                    src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
                    dest: '.tmp/scripts',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            },
            test: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'test/spec',
                    src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
                    dest: '.tmp/spec',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            }
        },
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false,
                assetCacheBuster: false
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
                }
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },
        // not used since Uglify task does concat,
        // but still available if needed
        /*concat: {
            dist: {}
        },*/
        requirejs: {
            dist: {
                // Options: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js
                options: {
                    // `name` and `out` is set by grunt-usemin
                    // dir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
                    baseUrl: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                    optimize: 'none', // uglify, uglify2, closure, closure.keepLines, none
                    // TODO: Figure out how to make sourcemaps work with grunt-usemin
                    // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/30
                    //generateSourceMaps: true,
                    // required to support SourceMaps
                    // http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#sourcemapcomments
                    preserveLicenseComments: false,
                    useStrict: true,
                    wrap: true
                    //uglify2: {} // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2
                }
            }
        },
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            },
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.php'
        },
        usemin: {
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
            },
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.php'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            // This task is pre-configured if you do not wish to use Usemin
            // blocks for your CSS. By default, the Usemin block from your
            // `index.html` will take care of minification, e.g.
            //
            //     <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
            //
            // dist: {
            //     files: {
            //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
            //             '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            //             '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
            //         ]
            //     }
            // }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                    //collapseWhitespace: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true*/
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    src: '*.php',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },
        // Put files not handled in other tasks here
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        'bower_components/normalize-css/normalize.css'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },
        modernizr: {
            devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
            ],
            uglify: true
        },
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'compass',
                'coffee:dist',
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'coffee',
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                'coffee',
                'compass',
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin',
                'htmlmin'
            ]
        },
        bower: {
            options: {
                exclude: ['modernizr']
            },
            all: {
                rjsConfig: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'requirejs',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'modernizr',
        'copy:dist',
        'rev',
        'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

and

```
{
  "name": "sitename.com",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-bower-requirejs": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.10",
    "grunt-mocha": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-modernizr": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.3.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.1.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.1.1",
    "gateway": "~0.1.1",
    "connect-livereload": "~0.3.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  }
}
```